# i want to set img src dynamically to a specified div on the basis of image hover by using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 images here , one is main image and other three are small. what i am trying to do is on which small img i hover my mouse i want to change that img path to the main image,i cant find how to change dynamically path of img src.

here is plunkr link of my code please help me
http://plnkr.co/edit/lSGWmazML3PusGboSbVI

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
        width: 40%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg/2000px-Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/780417329096122368/Sb5hzGkT.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_MWz5rMNRrCo/THLd749oLcI/AAAAAAAACEE/ZpjNG5iMnfs/s1600/Number-512-800x600-Pixels.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/WA-512.svg/70px-WA-512.svg.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script></script>
</body>
```

Comment: $('thatimgClass').hover(funciton(){// to change the img src // $(this).attr('src','url of image');}),function(){//make change when mouse out  $(this).attr('src','url of some other image');});   .... You can use attr or Prop to set the value of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".small_img").hover(function(){
     var smallImgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
     jQuery("#main_img").attr('src',smallImgSrc);
   })
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    img {
      width: 40%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <img id="main_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg/2000px-Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg.png">
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="small_img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/780417329096122368/Sb5hzGkT.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
     <img class="small_img" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_MWz5rMNRrCo/THLd749oLcI/AAAAAAAACEE/ZpjNG5iMnfs/s1600/Number-512-800x600-Pixels.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="small_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/WA-512.svg/70px-WA-512.svg.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use this, hope you want this. Revert me in case of any issue

Comment: You should always add some sort of explanation to an answer, so the OP know what you did and why

Comment: Sure Andersen, I will take care this point for my next post. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` to achive what you want.

In these functions you would use `.attr()` to set the `src`.

```js
$(".container img").mouseover(function() {
  $('.jumbotron img').attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg/2000px-Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg.png">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/780417329096122368/Sb5hzGkT.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_MWz5rMNRrCo/THLd749oLcI/AAAAAAAACEE/ZpjNG5iMnfs/s1600/Number-512-800x600-Pixels.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/WA-512.svg/70px-WA-512.svg.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want dont want to change image when mousehover is out ?

Comment: i mean when mouse hover is out image path again change

Comment: @AmitChauhan I've changed the code, so now it will change the image when you hover and do nothing when you leave as your requested

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
  $(document).ready(function(){

   
$('.row img').hover(function(){
  
$("#mainImg").attr('src',($(this).attr('src')));

});
 
 });
```

```css
img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <img id="mainImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg/2000px-Bundesstra%C3%9Fe_512_number.svg.png">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/780417329096122368/Sb5hzGkT.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_MWz5rMNRrCo/THLd749oLcI/AAAAAAAACEE/ZpjNG5iMnfs/s1600/Number-512-800x600-Pixels.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/WA-512.svg/70px-WA-512.svg.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LdKGXxKi9aaxdvOHIsSj

Comment: @Amit Chauhan.  See this snippet http://plnkr.co/edit/LdKGXxKi9aaxdvOHIsSj